# Laravel Api response for one user

Tags: php, laravel

I wonder if this is possible, imagine that I have this reply on a `laravel` api when I call all the users, I wonder if it's possible just calling one of them and showing the information related to that user like `public/api/users/1`

I cannot find the words to search a reply for that, so sorry if its a repost.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "a",
    "BI": 123,
    "morada": "1245"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "b",
    "BI": 123456,
    "morada": "1p231p2oi3"
}
```

Calling just through `public/api/users/1` gives me a blank page, that would supposed to be the `id` of the user right?

Answer (score 1):

As a straightforward implementation of that, you could add to routes.php file:

```
Route::get("api/users/{id}", function($id) {
   return App\User::find($id); 
});
```

As of Laravel 5.2 framework also supports [model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding):

```
Route::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\User $user) {
    return $user;
});
```

EDIT:

Outputing only certain attributes:

```
Route::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\User $user) {
   return response()->json([
      "id"   => (int) $user->id,
      "name" => $user->name
   ]);
});
```

Comment: I would recommend returning the raw output of the model. I'd suggest formatting it to the fields you want to display.

Comment: Yeah, it was a straightforward solution. You could also put it inside controller, use Fractal etc...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using something like the below.

```
Route::get('api/users/{user}', function ($id) {
    $user = App\User::first($id);

    $content = [
       'id' => $user->id,
       'nome' => $user->nome,
       'BI' => $user->BI,
       'morada' => $user->morada
    ];

    return response($content, 200)
                  ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
});
```